# Unable to create NSDate from NSString with date parts

Tags: objective-c, ios7, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have an app (iOS 7.1.1 and XCode 5.1) where I'm trying to create a date from parts of another date (either the date or time is missing from the text fields).  This is my code:

```
//  get recurring start and stop dates
NSArray *dateParts = [avc.boApptStart.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSLog(@"\n\ndateParts: %@", dateParts);  //  dateParts: ("2014-11-07", "09:00", AM)

dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HHmm a"];
NSString *tempRecurrsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@",avc.oRecurrsStart.text, [dateParts objectAtIndex: 1], [dateParts objectAtIndex: 2]];
NSDate *recurrsStartDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString: tempRecurrsString];
NSLog(@"\n\nreccurrsStartDate: %@  avc.oRecurrsStart.text: %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:recurrsStartDate], avc.boApptStart.text);

tempRecurrsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@",avc.oRecurrsEnd.text, [dateParts objectAtIndex: 1], [dateParts objectAtIndex: 2]];
NSDate *recurrsEndDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString: tempRecurrsString];
NSLog(@"\n\nrecurrsEndDate: %@  tempDateString: %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:recurrsEndDate], tempRecurrsString);
```

This is the edited result (removed app name, etc) of the above code displayed in the console:

```
reccurrsStartDate: (null)  
avc.oRecurrsStart.text: 2014-11-07 09:00 AM

recurrsEndDate: (null)  
tempDateString: 2014-12-31 09:00 AM
```

The question is:  why is this NOT being converted to NSDate?  I think I have all the parts wired correctly, and for the life of me I can't see what I've forgotten.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where?  The lame compiler found no errors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you are missing a `:` in `[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HHmm a"];` between `HH` and `mm`.
Secondly you should use `hh` which is 12 hours and not `HH` which is 24 hours.

So final string ends up as:
`[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"];`

For more information about date formatting look at the [ICU User Guide](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime).

Comment: Unbelievable!  I use both 12 and 24 hour time formats; never did think that it would make that much of a difference (I forgot the colon, which applies to both).  Thank you for your time and advice.  SD